# Lose money when poker server goes down?

Tags: online

For those of you that play online poker, what happens when the servers go down in the middle of a hand? What are the online poker companies policies for when servers go down in the middle of a hand? Do you lose your chips or do they refund you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So typically if there is something like a server update this sort of situation won't happen (they'll just deal a "final hand" until the update completes).

If a player gets disconnected during a hand sites typically do one of the following:

- Treat him as if he were all-in
- Force him to check all streets and fold to any bet

So in the case of a server crash (which I think would be really, really rare) all players involved in the hand would just check the rest of the hand down (and I'll presume any bets that haven't yet been called would just be taken back). If the software can't support this scenario I guess they would just act as if that last hand never happened.

For tournaments, typically money will be refunded if the tournament is still in the early stages or the money will somehow be distributed to the remaining players in the later stages (where the distribution is either based on a chip count, ICM, or some other method).

Answer (score 2):

From what I know, it depends on the site.
Each site has it's rules. You should read the user agreement and the 'terms & condition' section to fully understand the site policy regarding server's failure.

Amigal